# Can I automate actions on Windows Start Menu using pywinauto?

Tags: pywinauto

I want to click on Windows Start Menu and check if my application is showing up. I then want to expand it and check which tools are showing up under this application and then I want click on one of these tools. Can I automate this using pywinauto?

Comment: Yes, you can. But Start menu has different GUI hierarchy for Win7, Win8 and Win10.

Comment: Any more details?